# pubCenter - one ad unit in two pages?

Tags: windows-phone-7, ads

I have application that has two Pages. In pubcenter I registered ad unit for this app. Can I put adControl in these two pages with the same ad unit or should I create separate ad units for each pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same ad units. You can use the same ad unit on as many pages as you like in your app.

Answer (score 1):

You can even use the same unit ad in multiple WP7 application, but after you wont have a clear vision on what application is bringing you how many views.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same AdUnits if you want to show ads from same categories. Use different ones if you want to show ads from different categories.